# How to insert a record or multiple records using entity framework core using dbcontext (soap ui sends data to asp.net core via api call)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When the entity framework receives the input in form of a post request from soap ui, it should insert the data record or multiple data records(rows) into the BdpMigrationList table and return a confirmation. BdpMigrationList was added to entity using sccafold command.

Model:

```
public class BDPHMMigModel
{ 
    public string CmNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime CmDate { get; set; }
    public string Ipact { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Circuit { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string SourceDevice { get; set; }
    public string SourceInterface { get; set; }
    public string SourceInterfaceLag { get; set; }
    public string DestDevice { get; set; }
    public string DestInterface { get; set; }
    public string DestInterfaceLag { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Data Access layer code: Please also recommend which class type should I use in the DAL code.

```
    public async Task<int> AddBdpHmMigData(BdpMigrationList migrationList)
    {
        var context = new IpReservationContext();
        object newcircuit = new BdpMigrationList
            {
                CmNo = migrationList.CmNo,
                CmDate = migrationList.CmDate,
                Ipact = migrationList.Ipact,
                Site = migrationList.Site,
                Version = migrationList.Version,
                Circuit = migrationList.Circuit,
                Customer = migrationList.Customer,
                SourceDevice = migrationList.SourceDevice,
                SourceInterface = migrationList.SourceInterface,
                SourceInterfaceLag = migrationList.SourceInterfaceLag,
                DestDevice = migrationList.DestDevice,
                DestInterface = migrationList.DestInterface,
                DestInterfaceLag = migrationList.DestInterfaceLag
            };
            context.Add(newcircuit);
            context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBdpHmMigData([FromBody]BDPHMMigModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var miglistID = await BdpHmDao.AddBdpHmMigData(model);
                if (miglistID > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(miglistID);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        return BadRequest();
```

BdpMigrationList class in entity:

```
[Table("BDP_Migration_List")]
public partial class BdpMigrationList
{
    [Required]
    [Column("CM_No")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CmNo { get; set; }
    [Column("CM_date", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime CmDate { get; set; }
    [Column("IPACT")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Ipact { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Site { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Circuit { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    [Column("Source_Device")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SourceDevice { get; set; }
    [Column("Source_Interface")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SourceInterface { get; set; }
    [Column("Source_Interface_Lag")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SourceInterfaceLag { get; set; }
    [Column("Dest_Device")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DestDevice { get; set; }
    [Column("Dest_Interface")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DestInterface { get; set; }
    [Column("Dest_Interface_Lag")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DestInterfaceLag { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

dbcontext:

```
public partial class IpReservationContext : DbContext
{
    public IpReservationContext()
    {
    }

    public IpReservationContext(DbContextOptions<IpReservationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BdpMigrationList> BdpMigrationList { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BdpMigrationList>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Circuit).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.CmNo).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Customer).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.DestDevice).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.DestInterface).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.DestInterfaceLag).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Ipact).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Site).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.SourceDevice).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.SourceInterface).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.SourceInterfaceLag).IsUnicode(false);
        });            
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

getting the following errors:

1. Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'homing_matrix_api.Model.BDPHMMigModel' to 'homing_matrix_api.Entity.IpReservation.BdpMigrationList'    homing-matrix-api   C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Controllers\BdpHmController.cs 55  Active
2. Error    CS0161  'BdpHmDao.AddBdpHmMigData(BdpMigrationList)': not all code paths return a value homing-matrix-api   C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Data\BdpHmDao.cs   51  Active
3. Warning  CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    homing-matrix-api   C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Data\BdpHmDao.cs   51  Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

Fix your controller code:

```
using ... Data Access layer name space

....
......

var bdp=new bdpHmDao();

var miglistID = await bdp.AddBdpHmMigData(model);
```

Fix your action code

```
public async Task<int> AddBdpHmMigData(BDPHMMigModel model)
{
    using (var context = new IpReservationContext())
    {
        var newcircuit = BdpMigrationList
        {
            CmNo = model.CmNo,
            CmDate = model.CmDate,
            Ipact = model.Ipact,
            Site = model.Site,
            Version = model.Version,
            Circuit = model.Circuit,
            Customer = model.Customer,
            SourceDevice = model.SourceDevice,
            SourceInterface = model.SourceInterface,
            SourceInterfaceLag = model.SourceInterfaceLag,
            DestDevice = model.DestDevice,
            DestInterface = model.DestInterface,
            DestInterfaceLag = model.DestInterfaceLag
        };

        context.Set<BdpMigrationList>().Add(newcircuit);
        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bikram I updated the code the way I think it should be. I have to gess since I don' t  see your dbcontext.

Comment: I have added the dbcontext and class in the code above. Please have a look. Also please have a look at the controller as well as its giving me the error which i posted above.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. Try it and tell me what is the error now.

Comment: Error CS4016 Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'int' rather than 'Task<int>' homing-matrix-api C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Data\BdpHmDao.cs 75 Active

Comment: @Bikram Sorry just add await. See my update.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0161 'BdpHmDao.AddBdpHmMigData(BDPHMMigModel)': not all code paths return a value homing-matrix-api C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Data\BdpHmDao.cs 51 Active

Comment: Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BdpHmDao.AddBdpHmMigData(BDPHMMigModel)' homing-matrix-api C:\Repositories\HomingMatrix\HomingMatrixAPI\Controllers\BdpHmController.cs 55 Active

Comment: i am getting the above two errors, now. second one is from my controller code.

Comment: Yes, it  means that in AddBdpHmMigData([FromBody]BDPHMMigModel model)  model is null

Comment: Can you show your view where is your action called?

Comment: I don't have any views. its built without the view.

Comment: I want to send all the column values from sap ui using a post method. then I expect this code to insert the data into the sql database.

Comment: it will be null initially because the input data will come from the sap ui post api call. also the table in sql server is empty(I don't think this is the problem though.)

Comment: Did you check the model  in  public async Task<IActionResult> AddBdpHmMigData([FromBody]BDPHMMigModel model) ? If it is empty try to remove [FromBody]. And remove [httpPOST] too.

Comment: still the same errors and if I remove httppost then how would it recognize the post request coming from ui .

Comment: Just try it and has nothing to do with ui.

Comment: @Bikram And fix  your controller code too.

Comment: seems like it worked fine now. thanks a bunch. I will try to do an api call now. thank you  :)